# Mix and match in dynamic framework Objective C and Swift with a Swift class implementing a Objective Protocol but cant find the definition

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, cocoapods

This is the setup we have. We have a Pod i.e a dynamic framework with Objective C and Swift Classes which works fine in most cases but recently we had a "SwiftClass" implementing a "ObjcProtocol". And we need to use this "SwiftClass" in Objective C code. So when the "MixAndMatchFramework-Swift.h" is generated it has the definition of the "SwiftClass" but it does not have the definition of the "ObjcProtocol" since it cannot be redefined in "MixAndMatchFramework-Swift.h" that will be a duplicate definition. Now what does try to do is include a header but the header is non existent like "<"MixAndMatchFramework/MixAndMatchFramework.h">". Now I tried manually adding the header with exact same name and including the header import to the "ObjcProtocol" definition but then it gives 20 other errors. Even though the content of that protocol only requires UIKit and Foundation.

And now these 20 or so errors reporting headers not found etc is very similar to the errors we got when we initially started mix and match and seemed related to the auto generated umbrella header by CocoaPods. We fixed that particular issue by specifying a custom modulemap in the xcconfig with explicit path to our manually added umbrella header( which had only the imports of Objective C Classes used in Swift) and that fixed the issue. But the errors have resurfaced again with the above mentioned scenario

We are using Xcode 8.2.1 with latest Swift 3.X with Cocoapads 1.1
Any takers.....

Answer (score 0):

Setting `Use Header Maps` to `Yes` fixed this issue for me.

When I ran into this issue last year, I made a sample app to try and reproduce the issue so I could file a radar bug with Apple.  In doing so, I determined that enabling `Use Header Maps` in the build settings was the key to whether this worked correctly or not.

I never filed a bug with Apple since it seemed like an edge case (and this value is `Yes` by default in newly created projects... it was off in ours since it was an old code base).

Update: I've also run into similar issues when the `Header Search Paths` were wrong or when file references for the headers in the `Build Phases` got messed up.